# Grouped query still showing duplicates

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a weird problem with MS Access, where a grouped query still shows what appears to be like identical strings

The query is as basic as it can be, so for instance

```
SELECT string, Count([string]) as Qty
FROM myTable
GROUP BY string
```

My result set however shows duplicated records that look exactly the same to the eye, but appear to be different to the application. Quite some rows as below are in the returned data:

```
| some value     | 5  |
| some value     | 15 |
| another value  | 10 |
```

etc, so the 'some_value' entry is in twice where it should be only once. 
The data originally comes from flat files, and imported into access using UTF8 encoding. Since the original source might use a variety on encodings my first guess would be that although visually the strings look the same, the encoding is probably different.

So my question : is it possible within access (vba) to validate the actual encoding of a string, or are their ways to encode strings to the same format ?

Or is there something else that might cause this behavior ? I've verified that the strings are identical for the eye, there are no white spaces or anything else visible that might cause the difference, so it's pretty clear the difference is on a non visual level (if that makes any sense at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I was able to fix it in the meantime, using the Asc() function on the string learned me that not all spaces are equal, I had a few using charset 32 (basic space) and some were using charset 160 (non breaking space). Using a replace function to change all non breaking spaces in standard spaces fixed the problem.

Good to keep in mind if someone else has the issue, traverse through your strings character by character and compare the Asc() values...

Comment: Out of curiosity, see if this works, select Trim(string),Count(*) as Qty
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Trim(string)

Comment: Hi Thinkingcap, trimming didn't work (which was the first I suspected also) as it was the space between 2 words that was different. In one case it was using a basic space character (32), in another one the 160 character. Looked exactly the same to the naked eye, but PC's don't think like that. Was a nice one in the end...